# UITableView Change the cell style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 table views I want to customise the cell  style of the second view depending on the selected row in the first table view. it works when in customising the accessories but it does't for the style. am using iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1
as i using the following code

thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([selectedRow isEqualToString:@"Cars"]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton];

    }
    if ([selectedRow isEqualToString:@"Houses"]) {
       NSArray *temp = [[dic objectForKey:selectedRow]valueForKey:@"Job"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
        cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];             
    }
    if ([selectedRow isEqualToString:@"Libraries"]) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't change a cell's style without creating a new cell.

The line:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
```

makes no sense. You are trying to change the cell's selection style by passing in a enum value for a cell's style. That's two different concepts.

When you want to update a cell's style (not the selection style), you need to call `UITableView initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` again passing in the desired style.